# wp-admin seems to be redirecting

Tags: login, errors

I'm having a strange problem with my w-admin login. This has only started since I upgraded to 3.0

When I go to wp-admin, the login form appears as normal, but when I enter my username and pass, I am presented with the login form again every time.
Using the password recovery feature results in an email not found error. I know the username password and email are correct, b/c I have access to the mysql database and I can see the values (at least the user name and email).

Anyone have any ideas of what could be going wrong?

Comment: 1. What is the type of web server?
2. Did you try accessing a url like http://example.com/wp-admin/index.php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main cause I've seen for this is incompatible plugins.  Via FTP, either download and delete all your plugins, or rename the existing plugins folder to plugins-old (or whatever) and make a new plugins folder.

After this, copy your plugins from the old folder to the new folder one by one until the problem reappears.  At that point, you have your culprit.  Look for an updated version (after deleting the offending plugin from the new plugins folder so you can log in) of the offending plugin and go from there.

Answer (score 1):

probably the upgrade did not go too well.  I suggest disabling all plugins, reuploading all the WP3 files (except the content of the wp-content folder) and then redoing the wp-admin/upgrade.php, then if the problem persists, look at the wp_users table see if your account still exists.

Answer (score 0):

I see this happen from time to time and it seems to be a long standing problem. I have noticed it since at least 2.6.

While I can't explain why it happens I have found that if I manually re-enter the "http://yourdomain.com/wp-admin" url (not wp-login.php) after my first login attempt that redirects it will take me straight to the dashboard.